# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 issue , Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-collection

if news_to_date is empty i get syntax error, how can i check if news_to_date is empty or not? Code below, thanks

```
\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime $stdlibDateTime, 

$currentTime = $this->_date->date();
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','sku'));     
$collection->addFieldToFilter('news_from_date', ['lteq' => $currentTime])
        ->addFieldToFilter('news_to_date', ['gteq' => $currentTime])
        ->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code instead:

```
$todayStartOfDayDate = $this->_date->date()->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$todayEndOfDayDate = $this->_date->date()->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('entity_id','sku'));

$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
        'news_from_date',
        [
            'or' => [
                0 => ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEndOfDayDate],
                1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
            ]
        ],
        'left'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'news_to_date',
        [
            'or' => [
                0 => ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStartOfDayDate],
                1 => ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')],
            ]
        ],
        'left'
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        [
            ['attribute' => 'news_from_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
            ['attribute' => 'news_to_date', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')],
        ]
    );

$collection->setOrder('sort_order', 'ASC');
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: \ Zend_news_from_dateDb_Expr replaced with \ Zend_Db_Expr and it works great, thanks

Comment: with \Zend_news_from_dateDb_Expr i getting error :)

Comment: Great. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Comment: You can edit my answer as well, as you found a bug in it

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try something like this

```php
$collection->addFieldToFilter('news_to_date',  ['neq' => NULL, 'gteq' => $currentTime]);
```

code is not tested, but should work :)